# vuejs Datable is not working with api's fetched data

Tags: vue.js, datatable, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-data-tables

I want to display the data in table using vue-datatable but it is not working.
Here is the code that i am using ,i am getting data in json format but it is not appending with datatable
can anyone help me in this or any better way to do this.
Thanks in Advance

`////main.js////
import Vue from 'vue'
import { VuejsDatatableFactory } from 'vuejs-datatable';
Vue.use( VuejsDatatableFactory );`

```js
<script>
  import axios from 'axios';
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      drawer: null,
       columns: [
                    {label: 'id', field: 'recData.id'},
                    {label: 'user ID', field: 'recData.userId'},
                    {label: 'Title', field: 'recData.title'},
                    {label: 'Description', field: 'recData.body'},
                ],
                recData:[]
    }),

    created() {
              //api for getting posts details
            const token = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
            axios({
                    method: 'get',
                    url: token,
                })
                .then((response) => {
                    this.recData = response.data;
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    this.errors = error;
                })   

    },
  }
</script>
```

```html
   <v-content>
      <v-container class="fill-height" fluid>
        <v-row align="center" justify="center">
          <span class="mb-5">{{ recData }}</span>
         <datatable :columns="columns" :data="recData"></datatable>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
```

[image]

Comment: Try to console.log('cheking my data',response.data); and check data

Comment: @MohammadUsman i am getting data  see in above code i have mentioned in span tag but it is not appending to data table

Comment: can you console it and show me what you are getting the data is it same as your database

Comment: @MohammadUsman check i have added  console pic

Comment: check my updated answer it is just a test

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to access in the array the object which is inside of another object which is not existed so try the below code try to access the object of an array like this  `{label: 'id', field: 'id'}`  not like that  `{label: 'id', field: 'recData.id'}`
this `this.recData = data` line need to be changed to this `this.recData = data.data`

Try this

```
    <script>
    import axios from 'axios';
    import Vue from "vue";
    import { VuejsDatatableFactory } from "vuejs-datatable";

    Vue.use(VuejsDatatableFactory);
    export default {
        data() {
            return {

                      drawer: null,
            columns: [
                    {label: 'id', field: 'id'},
                    {label: 'user ID', field: 'userId'},
                    {label: 'Title', field: 'title'},
                    {label: 'Description', field: 'body'},
                ],
                recData:[]

            };
        },
      created() {
                //api for getting posts details

                axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
                .then(({ data }) => (this.recData = data.data));

               },
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: i took reference from this example only it is working fine with static data but not with api fetched data

Comment: So it means the problem is in api  not in vuejstable

Comment: still no change

Comment: are you using only vuejs or  vuejs+laravel or something else?because I need to know from where you are getting the ```https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts```

Comment: i am just using vuejs+bootstrap4

Comment: I have updated the answer try it, it will work 100%

Comment: thanks @MohammadUsman for putting this much effort but  now it is showing some unexpected error "Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined"